# How do you access database error information when using Rails and Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model, error-handling

I am using find_by_sql to connect to a Postgres database and execute a database function. The database function executes a number of SQL statements and raises exceptions as required.

How do I trap the error code and error message raised by the Postgres function in Rails?

```
def self.validate_email(systemuserid, emailaddress)
  begin
    result = (self.find_by_sql(["SELECT fn_systemuser_validate_email(?, ?) AS returncode", 
                                systemuserid, emailaddress])).first
  rescue => err
    # I want to get access to the error code and error message here and act accordingly
    # errno = ??
    # errmsg = ??
    if errno == 10000
    end
  end
  return result[:returncode]
end
```

I started by trying to find this information in the connection object - no such luck.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Currently active record replaces the original error with an internal one without passing on the original with the new error. I cant understand why any one would want this.

So the only solution right now is to monkey patch ;)

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class AbstractAdapter
      def translate_exception(e, message)
        ActiveRecord::WrappedDatabaseException.new(message,e)
      end

      # Replaces
      # def translate_exception(e, message)
      #   # override in derived class
      #   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid.new(message)
      # end
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can get the original_exception.

```
def self.validate_email(systemuserid, emailaddress)
  begin 
    result = (self.find_by_sql(["SELECT fn_systemuser_validate_email(?, ?) AS returncode", systemuserid, emailaddress])).first
  rescue ActiveRecord::WrappedDatabaseException => e

    pgerror = e.original_exception

    # Exact api depends on PG version, check the docs for your version.
    puts "Doing my stuff: #{pgerror.result.result_error_message}"

  end
end
```

This works with pg version 0.11 and Rails 3.0.9. Will probably work with later versions.

Comment: If you don't like monkey patching go and vote up this pull request. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5641

Answer (score 2):

I let this one go for a while, (9 months!) but picked it up again due to a new impetus.

I used the monkey patch suggested by Darwin (sorry that the pull request didnt get the vote) and have then discovered that the code I need (with reference to http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Result.html) is as follows:

```
rescue ActiveRecord::WrappedDatabaseException => e

  pgerror = e.original_exception
  sqlstate = pgerror.result.error_field(PG::Result::PG_DIAG_SQLSTATE )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just look at `.cause`.

```
begin
  # whatever.
rescue => err
  p err.cause
end
```

Comment: Does this differ from what err is cast to as a string? Would that be the err.bracktrace?

Answer (score 0):

You can user the errors array of your model, like others database:

> errmsg = YourModel.errors[0].full_messages

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm afraid that this doesnt really help.

Comment: My understanding is that the errors array is used to present errors back to the user as a result of model validation.

This is different. I am looking for access to the SQLCode / SQLState returned by Postgres as a result of a find_by_sql call. 

This occurs well in advance of anything being added to the errors array. In fact, the point of this is that I am seeking to control exactly what is added to the errors array as a result of the SQL function call.

Comment: I cant see any documentation anywhere on how to get access explicitly to the SQL error code. Seems like the only option is to do string manipulation to extract it from the error message.

VERY unsatisfactory. I cant believe that the database handling is so inflexible so there MUST be a solution.